# Firestore Cascading Delete Of References

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I am creating a Firestore database designed for a social media network.

In my application, users can follow each other. For example, User A can follow User B. In Firestore I have a collection called `followers` that has an array of references.

My problem is that User A is following 5,000 other users. But User A just got deleted. Do I have to go through all those 5,000 collections and remove User A manually? Is there a Firestore feature/ability that will automatically remove any references of that user?

Screenshot of example User in my `followers` collection. How can I make my changes cascade if `UserA` is deleted from the `users` collection?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing provided by Firestore that will do this for you automatically.  You will have to write code to query for and manually remove the references to the deleted user.